# Multi-store Inventory

Tags: bigcommerce

Is it possible to set an inventory level for multiple stores for the same item. Example, I have 6 brick and mortar store, an ecommerce store, and a HQ. I want to add inventory from the Bigcommerce backend and choose the store it goes to. I need this functionality because from the brick and mortar stores I need to feed the inventory for this store to my POS system (which I am also developing and will be using APIs to interact with the chosen baackend).

Example:
Total Reporting Inventory for FooItem is 10 units

Store #1: 3 FooItems

Store #2: 7 FooItems

If I search from the POS at Store #1 I want to be able to know there are 3 physically at this store.

If they do a POS search from Store #3 there should be no inventory but alert there are 10 within across all stores (store transfers are a thing).

Any thoughts? I have tested Shopify and it also lacks this basic feature.

Comment: Most popular, hosted ecommerce platforms do not do this natively. If using Bigcommerce you will need a 3rd party solution to handle this or you will have to write dinner custom code and use the API. A few other platforms, such as Lead Commerce, can handle this but it is rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now it is imposible. You need 3rd party solution. I could advice you to use DEAR Inventory. They have plan to finish integration with BigCommerce till the end of Q1'2015.

Comment: As of 08/2019, has BigCommerce setup any native way to track multi-location quantities per SKU? It seems they have no documentation on how to do this? Would custom fields, variant metafields, or product variant options work?